# Enhancing Color Detection Accuracy in Real-Time: Dealing with Gray Color Issues

Tags: python, opencv, colors, python-imaging-library, detection

I am working on a color detection project that works fine under normal conditions. However, when I attempt real-time detection, I'm noticing that it tends to detect more gray colors than the actual colors. I believe this might be due to variations in lighting or brightness.

To address this issue, I have implemented a gamma correction technique by adjusting the image's brightness. Here is the relevant part of my code:

```py
def adjust_gamma(image, gamma=1.0):
    # build a lookup table mapping the pixel values [0, 255] to
    # their adjusted gamma values
    invGamma = 1.0 / gamma
    table = np.array([((i / 255.0) ** invGamma) * 255
        for i in np.arange(0, 256)]).astype("uint8")
    # apply gamma correction using the lookup table
    return cv2.LUT(image, table)

def to_pillow(cv_image: np.ndarray):
    image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(cv_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    adjusted_brightness = adjust_gamma(image_rgb, gamma=0.69)
    pillow_image = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(adjusted_brightness, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA))
    return pillow_image

def color(cv_image: np.ndarray, quality: int = 1):
    pillow_image = to_pillow(cv_image)
    rgb = fast_colorthief.get_dominant_color(np.asarray(pillow_image), quality=quality)
```

While this technique has helped improve color detection, I'm still experiencing some issues with detecting gray colors.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem or does anyone have suggestions on further improving the color detection accuracy under varying lighting conditions? Your insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!"

Comment: [mre] please. and you must explain this "fast_colorthief" thing and why you think that's not the problem.